# Display Department Code and Description in JSP drop down using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a DAO class which has a method which returns a java.util.List
where I am returning `Employee Department` and `Employee Department Code` from database.

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
    List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        emp.add(mapListEmployees(resultSet));
    }
    return emp ;
}
```

In my ManagedBean I would like to call `getEmployeeDetails()` method and populate this to a method called getEmpDetails

```
public List<Employee> getItems() {
    for (Employee employee: myDAO.getEmployeeDetails()) {
        list.add(employeeLabel.getEmployeeName(),
                employeeLabel.getEmployeeDepartment());
    }
}
```

But the problem is `list.add` doesn't allow to have two String arguments because I am getting

```
method add(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) not found in 
interface java.util.List
```

So how can I get the values from dao and load to a method in ManagedBean which returns List
and finally how can I call these in a JSP page using jstl as drop down component?
Something like

```
<select id="emp">
    <c:forEach >
        <option value="${item}">${item}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the EmployeeGroup is unique. So, you can use Map instead of list to get a key value structure. Underlie you can find the code to print the Map in the jsp using jstl

```
public List<Employee> getItems() {
   Map<String, String> mapObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (Employee employee: 
                 myDAO.getEmployeeDetails()) {
                map.put(employeeLabel.getEmployeeGroup(),
                         employeeLabel.getEmployeeGroupDescription());
            }
 }

JSP:
//Don't forget to add the mapObj to the request context
<select id="emp">
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${mapObj}">
            <option value="${item.key}">${item.value}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Comment: Raunak Agarwal So it is better to use Map instead of List? Any advantage in using Map? Thanks

Comment: Its more about your requirement. Since you want pair of values to be rendered on the jsp. It would be more cleaner. I would strongly suggest you to go through the java docs to understand it in more detail. As it is one of the most important data structure available in the java language.

Comment: Besides where do I need to add mapObj as request context?

Comment: The place where you are forwarding your request to the jsp i.e. either in your servlet or controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would skip all kinds of mappings. You can store List and use it directly from JSP by providing public getter for employeeDetails in your bean.

```
<select id="emp">
<c:forEach items="${beanName.employeeDetails}" var="res">
    <option value="${res.employeeGroup}">${res.employeeGroupDescription}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Be sure, your sql returns unique pairs by using DISTINCT in your sql or UNIQUE index.

Java code:

```
    private List<Employee> employeeDetails = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeDetails() {
    List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        emp.add(mapListEmployees(resultSet));
    }
    this.employeeDetails = emp;


    return this.employeeDetails;
}
```